# Convert url and query parameters into one query parameter:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an url:

```
var url = /company/overview
```

I have query params

```
var params = {
    campaign = "back-to-work"
    user = "1"
}
```

How can I convert these two values (originally extracted from `$location.path()` and `$location.search()`) into one query parameter called `return_to`. I will later attach this `return_to` query parameter to a login url.

Github do something similar when trying to access content that requires login:

```
https://github.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Forgs%2FCompany%2Fdashboard%3Fcampaign%3Dback-to-work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
encodeURIComponent($location.path())
```

which returns the following for this page

```
"%2Fquestions%2F39034879%2Fconvert-url-and-query-parameters-into-one-query-parameter"
```

You just add this as a param to you other url and you're good to go :)

Additional Info:
There are two encoding options in JavaScript:

- `encodeURI()` will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`
- `encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: `~!*()'`

See *[Best practice: escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)* for more details.